# JSDDM menu not working on Android

Tags: android

I used a drop down menu I had found on here about a year ago called a "jsddm" menu. It worked then on Androids and is now not working on Androids but works on iPhones. Can anyone help me figure out why? Thanks! EDIT- By Not working I mean  - it does not toggle down. The gallery link does not take anyone anywhere. It's the sub menu that is what takes users to the gallery. On Androids it does not even show the drop down at all.
Code * This is the original code (with my CSS mods) that I had found on here.

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var timeout         = 500;
var closetimer      = 0;
var ddmenuitem      = 0;

function jsddm_open()
{   jsddm_canceltimer();
    jsddm_close();
    ddmenuitem = $(this).find('ul').eq(0).css('visibility', 'visible');}

function jsddm_close()
{   if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.css('visibility', 'hidden');}

function jsddm_timer()
{   closetimer = window.setTimeout(jsddm_close, timeout);}

function jsddm_canceltimer()
{   if(closetimer)
    {   window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
        closetimer = null;}}

$(document).ready(function()
{   $('#jsddm > li').bind('mouseover', jsddm_open);
    $('#jsddm > li').bind('mouseout',  jsddm_timer);});

document.onclick = jsddm_close;
</script>
```

CSS

```
#jsddm
{   margin: 20px 0;
    text-align: center;

    }

    #jsddm li
    {   
        list-style: none;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #jsddm li a
    {   font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
        text-shadow: none;
        color:#000;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight:normal;
        padding: 3px 10px;

    }

    #jsddm li a:hover
    {   color:#000;
        text-decoration:underline;}

        #jsddm li ul
        {   margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            position: absolute;
            visibility: hidden;
            border-top: 1px solid white;
            font-size:.8em;}

            #jsddm li ul li
            {   float: none;
                display: inline}

            #jsddm li ul li a
            {   width: auto;
                background: #8e7967;
                color: #24313C}

            #jsddm li ul li a:hover
            {   background: #fff;}


HTML
<ul id="jsddm">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
    <li><a href="pricing.html">Pricing</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="gameheadgallery.html">Game Heads</a></li>
            <li><a href="birdsgallery.html">Birds</a></li>
            <li><a href="fishgallery.html">Fish</a></li>
            <li><a href="exoticsgallery.html">Exotics</a></li>
            <li><a href="mammalgallery.html">Mammals</a></li>
            <li><a href="europeans.html">Europeans</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="field.html">Field Care Video</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you update your answer to include what you mean by 'not working'

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. I'm new to this site. Not working - it does not toggle down. The gallery link does not take anyone anywhere. It's the sub menu that is what takes users to the gallery. On Androids it does not even show the drop down at all.

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try this question
[Making the "jsddm" menu to list sub menus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882805/making-the-jsddm-menu-to-list-sub-menus)

The answer there is what I would be doing - using CSS instead.

Here is a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Sjhab/

It is not mine, and I must add code to post a fiddle. But I'm sure it will help:

```
<ul id="jsddm">
<li><a href="#">JavaScript</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Drop Down Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">jQuery Plugin</a></li>
    <li class="b"><a href="#">Ajax Navigation</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">AJAXIFY</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Effect</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Slide Effect</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Fade Effect</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Opacity Mode</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Drop Shadow</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Semitransparent</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Navigation</a></li>
<li><a href="#">HTML/CSS</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
</ul>



#jsddm
{ margin: 0; padding: 0}

#jsddm li
{   float: left;
list-style: none;
font: 12px Tahoma, Arial}

#jsddm li a
{   display: block;
background: #20548E;
padding: 5px 12px;
text-decoration: none;
border-right: 1px solid white;
width: 70px;
color: #EAFFED;
white-space: nowrap}

#jsddm li a:hover
{   background: #1A4473}

#jsddm li ul
{   margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    opacity: 0;
}

#jsddm > li:hover ul,
#jsddm > li:hover ul li:hover ul
{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;    
}

#jsddm ul {

-webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out .5s;
-moz-transition: all .5s ease-out .5s;
-ms-transition: all .5s ease-out .5s;
-o-transition: all 5s ease-out.5s;
transition: all .5s ease-out.5s;
}


#jsddm > li:hover ul li ul {
    visibility: hidden;
}


#jsddm li ul li
{   float: none;
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}

#jsddm li ul li a
{   width: auto;
    background: #9F1B1B}

#jsddm li ul li a:hover
{   background: #7F1616}
```

Comment: I closed the tags and tried again and it didn't work. It worked previously, but just recently stopped working.

Comment: I saw that you had accepted the answer. Did it work after closing the tags, or do you mean before you posted this question it was working but then stopped?

Comment: It does not work after closing the tags. In general it worked months ago and just recently stopped working. I have not touched the site in months and I am now updating some photos for my client. He informed me last week that the gallery drop down does not work on Droids. I used to have a Droid (a few months ago) and it worked then. I don't have a Droid anymore to test on so I tried on my Kindle and he is right...they don't work. Site- kellerstaxidermy.com   If that helps if you have access to a Droid

Comment: If your code has not been changed, and it was working before, then something must have changed externally. Do you source your library from a CDN? Is the client using a new version of Android? Is it the Android stock browser?
My answer obviously is not right, so I shall delete shortly.

Comment: Good questions... I use host gator. The code is exactly how it is above. I can't control external issues, but still need the site to work. Do you have any suggestions on what else I can do or try? I'd prefer not to have to re-do the menus, but it sounds like I may need to!